# Is there a function for using Kish Tables in R?

Tags: r, function

I've been trying to apply a function using the last two values of rows in a data frame, and I want it to repeat this process using the last two values of every row. Here's the function I'm trying to apply.

Basically, I create a function that uses a Kish grid. A kish grid is a way of randomly selecting participants in a household survey. It's a 10x8 matrix, it looks like this.

```
kishvalues <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
                1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,
                1,2,1,4,4,4,4,4,
                1,1,2,1,5,5,5,5,
                1,2,3,2,1,6,6,6,
                1,1,1,3,2,1,7,7,
                1,2,2,4,3,2,1,8,
                1,1,3,1,4,3,2,1,
                1,2,1,2,5,4,3,2)
kishtable <- matrix(kishvalues, nrow=10, ncol=8, byrow=T); kishtable

> kishtable <- matrix(kishvalues, nrow=10, ncol=8, byrow=T); kishtable
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    2    2    2    2    2    2    2
 [3,]    1    1    3    3    3    3    3    3
 [4,]    1    2    1    4    4    4    4    4
 [5,]    1    1    2    1    5    5    5    5
 [6,]    1    2    3    2    1    6    6    6
 [7,]    1    1    1    3    2    1    7    7
 [8,]    1    2    2    4    3    2    1    8
 [9,]    1    1    3    1    4    3    2    1
[10,]    1    2    1    2    5    4    3    2
```

If I'm doing household interviews, let's say I visit my **7th** house of the day (rows), and there are **4** eligible participants for the interview (columns), I use the Kish table to select which of the four participants from youngest to oldest I have to choose in order to somewhat maintain randomness, and I would have to select the **3rd** participant of that household for the interview.

```
> kishtable <- matrix(kishvalues, nrow=10, ncol=8, byrow=T); kishtable
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    2    2    2    2    2    2    2
 [3,]    1    1    3    3    3    3    3    3
 [4,]    1    2    1    4    4    4    4    4
 [5,]    1    1    2    1    5    5    5    5
 [6,]    1    2    3    2    1    6    6    6
 [7,]    1    1    1   (3)   2    1    7    7
 [8,]    1    2    2    4    3    2    1    8
 [9,]    1    1    3    1    4    3    2    1
[10,]    1    2    1    2    5    4    3    2
```

Now, here is the function I'm using

```
kish <- function(house,ep){
  x <- kishtable[house,ep]
  print(x)
}

kish(house=7, ep=4)
[1] 3
```

How can I apply this function, but instead of doing it on two single values, do it on two vectors, one vector is the sequential number of the homes visited (1 - 10) and another vector representing the number of eligible participants which can vary from 1 - 8?

Hope I made sense, let me know if you need anything else to better understand the problem.

Comment: Use mapply or purrr::map

Comment: You do not need the table: `kt <- function(house, ep){1 + (house - 1) %% ep}`  will work directly, including with vectors (of equal length)

Comment: Hello Henry. I've never seen that operator before (%%). What does it do? Could you also explain how you figured out an equation that could replace the kish table?

Answer (score 1):

Use `cbind` for the `[`-index.

```r
homes <- c(7,8,10)
participants <- c(4,6,5)
kishtable[cbind(homes, participants)]
# [1] 3 2 5
```

Mapping to the following:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    2    2    2    2    2    2    2
 [3,]    1    1    3    3    3    3    3    3
 [4,]    1    2    1    4    4    4    4    4
 [5,]    1    1    2    1    5    5    5    5
 [6,]    1    2    3    2    1    6    6    6
 [7,]    1    1    1   (3)1  2    1    7    7
 [8,]    1    2    2    4    3   (2)2  1    8
 [9,]    1    1    3    1    4    3    2    1
[10,]    1    2    1    2   (5)3  4    3    2
```